# How to remove characters before and including an underscore?

Tags: linux, string, bash, unix, awk

In bash scripting what's an efficient way to do the following please?

```
var="fooo_barrrr"
```

What is the best way to remove all characters before and including the '_'  so that var becomes "barrrr" please?

Comment: what if you have more than one `_`? What part of the string do you want to keep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ var="fooo_barrrr"
$ echo ${var#*_}
barrrr
```

To change the var itself, `var=${var#*_}`.

Note this removes up to the first `_`:

```
$ var="fooo_barrr_r"
$ echo ${var#*_}
barrr_r
```

If you wanted to remove up to the last one, you would need to use `##` instead:

```
$ var="fooo_barrr_r"
$ echo ${var##*_}
r
```

---

See some alternatives:

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^[^_]*_//' <<< "foo_barrrr_r"
barrrr_r
```

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/^[^_]*_/,"")1' <<< "foo_barrrr_r"
barrrr_r
```

With `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '[^_]*_\K.*' <<< "foo_barrrr_r"
barrrr_r
```

In all cases, to store the new value in the same var, do `var=$(command <<< "$var")`.

Comment: `${var##*_}` removes up to last

Comment: Yep! I am using just `#` because I understand it is just the first one that matter. However, I am editing to also indicate this. Thanks

Comment: You can also use `expr "$var" : "[^_]*_\(.*\)"` if you are creating a comprehensive list :)

Answer (score 1):

Or, using `grep`:

```
echo fooo_barrrr | grep -oP '.*(?=_)'
```

To understand the meaning of each flag, use `grep --help`:

- `-P`, --perl-regexp

  PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
- `-o`, --only-matching

  show only the part of a line matching PATTERN

In order to avoid incorrect results when having more than two parts, you can use:

```
echo fooo_barrrr_xyz | grep -oP '.*?(?=_)' | head -1
```

Comment: Note this fails for `echo fooo_barrrr_ca | grep -oP '.*(?=_)'`

Comment: Indeed. I assumed OP only has two parts. Edited.

Comment: How does this count as "efficient", considering that there's a shell builtin?